# Content profile title token

Tags: tokens, users

I need a content profile title token. I downloaded [this small module](http://drupal.org/node/542728), but it works only for text_field and I need a title.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the Content Profile Tokens module? It is a sub-module of content profile 1.x.

Your content profile title could be a node title or a CCK field; the token [title] or [field_titlefieldname-raw] will provide the value you expect.

Comment: Yeah, i've tryed Content profile tokens module in then link that i've mentioned in the 1st post. But after its install i see only cck fields that i've created for profile content type, e.g. [content-profile-profile-city], [content-profile-profile-country] etc... But no title :( Maybe i downloaded wrong archive of this module? Can u link to urs archive?

Comment: Try token [title]. I have a drupal site where Content profile tokens module is disable but still I can get the title and cck field value from available tokens.

Comment: When i'm using a [title] token it displays just [title] it doesn't work at all. Thanks for this suggestion anyway. But do u know a different way to make content profile title as token?

Comment: help somebody pls!

Comment: tried this code: http://viju.tvercity.net/en/weblog/how-add-custom-token
but all what i get is a white screen of death after using this module.